# Mapping over array, reused child component props not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I'm working on a React App using Flux - the purpose of which is a standard shopping cart form.

The trouble I'm having is with mapping over some data, and rendering a child component for each iteration which needs local state in order to handle form data before submitting, as I'm getting conflicting props from within different functions.

The following component is the HTML table which contains a list of all products.

```
/*ProductList*/
export default React.createClass({
    getProductForms: function(product, index) {
        return (
            <ProductForm
                product={product}
                key={index}
            />
         )
    },
    render: function() {
        var productForms;

        /*this is set from a parent component, which grabs data from the ProductStore*/
        if(this.state.products) {
            productForms = this.state.products.map( this.getProductForms );
        }
        return (
            <div className="product-forms-outer">
                {productForms}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

However, each child component has a form, and if I understand correctly, the form values should be controlled by local state (?). The Render method always gets the expects props values, but I want to setState from props, so I can both pass initial values (from the store) and maintain control of form values.

However, `componentDidMount()` props always just returns the last iterated child. I've also tried `componentWillReceiveProps()` and `componentWillMount()` to the same effect.

```
/*ProductForm*/
export default React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        /*this.props: product-three, product-three, product-three*/
    },
    render: function() {
        /* this.props: product-one, product-two, product-three */
        <div className="product-form">
            <form>
                /* correct title */    
                <h4>{this.props.productTitle}</h4>
                /* This needs to be state though */
                <input 
                    value={this.state.quantity} 
                    onChange={this.handleQuantityChange}
                    className="product-quantity"
                 />
            </form>
        </div>
    }
});
```

Let me know if there's any more details that I can provide to make things more clear - I've removed other elements for simplicity's sake.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this make sense:  productForms = this.state.products.map( this.getProductForms ); Map function must return manipulated data.

Comment: @matticus_1120, You are iterating the `state.products` to render `ProductForm`s. So each `ProductForm` is supposed to get only a single product's data right?

Comment: @free-soul Yes, that's correct - each form is only one product.

Comment: @ved Yes that's the case. I need to manipulate/verify the data before using it within the form, therefore just using props won't work.

Answer (score 0):

this is strange. Alternatively, you can set your state in the constructor to empty values for every field e.g

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {quantity: ''};
}
```

and then in your render function do smthg like:

```
render: function() {
    let compQuantity = this.state.quantity || this.props.quantity;

    /* this.props: product-one, product-two, product-three */
    <div className="product-form">
        <form>
            /* correct title */    
            <h4>{this.props.productTitle}</h4>
            /* This needs to be state though */
            <input 
                value={compQuantity} 
                onChange={this.handleQuantityChange}
                className="product-quantity"
             />
        </form>
    </div>
}
```

This way on the first render it'll use whatever is passed in the props and when you change the value, the `handleQuantityChange` function will set the state to the new value and `compQuantity` will then take its value from state.

Comment: Thanks @Nazim, that's a creative solution, and that works for conditionally using state or props with quantity - however, and I didn't include this, I need some other hidden fields that won't change after the form is rendered (unique ID), therefore I need to set it in the state.

Answer (score 0):

So I've figured out what the issue was. I wasn't using the key within the `getProductForms` method properly. I was debugging and just output the index in each form - it was always 0, 1, 2, 3... (obviously). So I looked into how those were relevant to the state for each one.

Given that the order of the array I was using (most recent first), the first iteration *always* had an index and key of 0, even though it was the newest item. So React probably just assumed the '0' item was meant to be the same from the beginning. I know there's a lot of nuances of react that I don't totally understand, but I think this proves that the state of a looped component is directly associated with it's key.

All I had to do was to use a different value as a key - which was a unique ID I have with each product, and not just use the array index. Updated code:

```
/*ProductList*/
getProductForms: function(product, index) {
    return (
        <div key={product.unique_id}>
            <ProductForm
                product={product}
            />
        </div>
     )
},
```